# How to remove newline from bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing for a space-constrained medium and I need my bibliography to be as compact as possible. This means removing almost all whitespace from bibliography entries, even paragraph skips between \bibitems.

Instead of having the bibliography like this:

[1] A. Anton et al. A Technique for Formatting Bibliographies, ArXiv, 2020.

[2] B.B. Brett and B. Ballot. Bibliography Formatting, BAM, 2020.

[3] C. Coomb. Characteristics of a Good Bibliography Formatting, Corr, 2020.

I would it to be like this:

**[1]** A. Anton et al. A Technique for Formatting Bibliographies, ArXiv, 2020. **[2]** B.B. Brett and B. Ballot. Bibliography Formatting, BAM, 2020. **[3]** C. Coomb. Characteristics of a Good Bibliography Formatting, Corr, 2020.

I found this suggestion online:

http://bibdesk-users.661331.n2.nabble.com/Very-compact-bibliography-styles-td1332196.html

But his solution produces strange spacings after each bibitem (it seems to be trying to justify the text in some strange way). I've tried meddling with his suggestion, removing items but no configuration gave me what I wanted.

I'm using overleaf to compile the latex file. Here's a working example:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@misc{a,
  author    = {A. Anton and
               others},
  title     = {A Technique for Formatting Bibliographies},
  journal = {ArXiv},
  year      = {2020}
}

@misc{b,
  author    = {B. Brett and
               B. Ballot},
  title     = {Bibliographies Formatting},
  journal = {BAM},
  year      = {2020}
}

@misc{c,
  author    = {C. Coomb},
  title     = {Characteristics of a Good Bibliography Formatting},
  journal = {Corr},
  year      = {2020}
}

@misc{d,
    author  = {D. Damiani and
                others},
    title   = {Direct Bibliographies for Latex: A Study on How to Produce Direct Bibliographies},
    journal = {DankJournal},
    year    = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \begin{inparaenum}%
      \list{\textbf{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}}%
           {\@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist\end{inparaenum}}
\renewcommand\newblock{}
\makeatother

\title{Bibliography Example}
\author{\LaTeX{} Stack Exchange User}
\date{August 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Here we cite \cite{a,b,c} and \cite{d}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

Citing 1,2,3 and 4 gives this output:

[image: Big space between 1st and 2nd bibitems]

While citing only 1,2, and 3

```latex
\section{Introduction}

Here we cite \cite{a,b,c} and nothing else.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{main}
```

[image: Huge space before first entry]

Is there any way to achieve such formatting for a bibliography in LaTeX?